# What's the best way to do many-to-many in Persistent Yesod?

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

So my /config/models looks like this.

```
Person
  name Text
Car
  name Text
PersonCar
  personId PersionId eq
  carId CarId eq
  UniquePersonCar personId carId
```

Assume the inputs in the database are `Person "Batman"` `Person "Superman"` `Car "SUV"` `Car "Ford"` respectively.

I'm currently doing this to link them up in my Handler.

```
runDB $ do
  person <- selectFirst [PersonName ==. "Batman"] []
  car    <- selectFirst [Carname ==. "SUV"] []
  let Entity personId _ = case person of
                            Just info -> infor
                            Nothing -> error "no such Person"
  let Entity carId _ = case car of
                            Just info -> infor
                            Nothing -> error "no such Car"
  _ <- insert $ PersonCar personId carId
```

Is there an easier way to do this?  Is there a convention for doing such expression?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's currently no shorthand for this kind of a query (that I can think of, at least).

Answer (score 1):

calls to error will halt your app. [logError](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/latest/doc/html/Yesod-Core.html#v%3alogError) may be better.

This is shorter:

```
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as DCL

runDB $ do
    mbPersonId <- runResourceT $ selectKeys [PersonName ==. "Batman"] [] $$ DCL.head
    mbCarId    <- runResourceT $ selectKeys [CarName ==. "SUV"] [] $$ DCL.head

    case (mbPersonId, mbCarId) of
        (Just personId, Just carId) -> do
              _ <- insert $ PersonCar personId carId
              return ()

        _ -> $(logError) "error looking for Batman and SUV"
```

Comment: I'm doing it under a handler, it's giving me parse error, any ideas?
`postFromR :: Handler RepHtml
postFormR = do
  case result of
    FormSuccess res -> _ <- runDB$insert$ PersonCar persionId carId
    _ -> $(logError) "error"`

Comment: @HHC, I have added a block around the insert line, that needed a return expression afterwards.
Tested with a yesod installation, grab the code again. Check your model names (PesionId instead of PersonId, PesonCar instead PersonCar)